# New to C... getting "UArray2.h:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token" on an unfinished function declaration

Tags: c, struct

I'm working on a CS project for school, but I seem to be getting this odd error which is pretty unhelpful. My partner and I can't seem to figure it out.

It says "UArray2.h:18: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token" on the first function declaration my .h file (UArray2_new).

It's followed by repeated "error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token" on every line with a function declaration. Any ideas? I included a blank main in mine, so you could see that it couldn't have been a compile issue. I used "gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror UArray2.c" for compiling.

```
//UArray2.h                                                                  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#ifndef UARRAY2_INCLUDED
#define UARRAY2_INCLUDED

struct UArray2_T{
    int width, height;                                                     
};   

extern UArray2_T * UArray2_new(int height, int width, int size);
extern void UArray2_free(UArray2_T * uarray2);                                                                
extern void * UArray2_at(UArray2_T * uarray2, int column, int row);
extern int UArray2_size(UArray2_T * uarray2);
extern int UArray2_columns(UArray2_T * uarray2);
extern int UArray2_rows(UArray2_T * uarray2);
static int UArray2_index(UArray2_T * uarray2, int col, int row);

#endif
```

And here is the .c file

```
//UArray.c                                                                          
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "UArray2.h"                                                             

int main()
{

     return 0;
}

UArray2_T * UArray2_new(int height, int width, int size)
{
    T newArray=malloc(sizeof(UArray2_T));
    newArray->height=height;
    newArray->width=width;
    (void) size;                            
    return newArray;
}

void UArray2_free(UArray2_T * uarray2)
{
    (void) uarray2;
    //need to write                                                                 

}

void * UArray2_at(UArray2_T * uarray2, int column, int row)
{

    (void) uarray2;
    int index=UArray2_index(uarray2, column, row);
    (void) index;
    //if(index>0 && index<=column*row)                                              
    //return UArray_at(uarray2->UArray, index);                                     
    //else                                                                          
    //throw an error                                                                
    char * k="hi"; //dummy variables
    return k;
}

int UArray2_size(UArray2_T * uarray2)
{
    //UArray_size(uarray2->UArray);                                                 
    return 0;
}
int UArray2_columns(UArray2_T * uarray2){
    return uarray2->width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere you have `UArray2_T *`, you should replace it with `struct UArray2_T *`. The `struct` keyword is required for `C` (but *not* in `C++`), when you refer to a `struct` type.

The standard way to avoid this is to use `typedef`, for example:

```
typedef struct {
    int width, height;                                                     
} UArray2_T;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, saying `struct Foo` does *not* introduce a new type called `Foo`. The type is called `struct Foo`.

You can create an alias for the type name, like so:

```
typedef struct UArray2_T UArray2_T;
```

Doing so should fix your errors.

Comment: @ManVsCode No, in C99, he would also be missing a `struct` or a `typedef`. That part of the language hasn't changed.

Comment: Please excuse, but this advice makes him created ugly code ... @unwind

Answer (score 0):

I would move the structure to the .c file. This will hide the structure's internals.

```
struct UArray2_T { // move to the .c file
    int width, height;                                                     
};
```

Add a forward declaration to the .h file, like this:

```
struct UArray2_T;
```

Comment: ... and change all function declarations to use `struct UArray2_T` but `UArray2_T` only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to typedef your struct, or use the struct keyword everwhere. I like this style:

```
typedef struct {
    int data1;
    char data2;
} newtype;
```